# How to use random text in UILocalNotifications?

Tags: arrays, swift, uilocalnotification, arc4random

I'm trying to make an app that will receive local notifications with random text. I used some code but it's not working well. It's coming only "006" or "005", and it won't change.

The code that I used is:

```
let myArray = ["000", "001", "002", "003", "004", "005", "006"]


let notification = UILocalNotification()
notification.alertBody = myArray[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(myArray.count)))] // text that will be displayed in the notification
notification.fireDate = NSDate()  // right now (when notification will be fired)
notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName // play default sound
notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.NSHourCalendarUnit // this line defines the interval at which the notification will be repeated

UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

Can you please show me where I made mistake ? Thanks.

Comment: Does this code get called once but you are launching the app multiple times? arc4random_uniform is probably (I can't be bothered to look it up) repeatedly random, and if is therefore always running with the same seed then it will always produce the same output. If its repeatedly random you need the change the seed to something like the current time in milliseconds then modulus the result with the array count.

Comment: @ThePumpingLama I got the logic of this. The problem is in `notification.alertBody = myArray[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(myArray.count)))]`. Is it possible to execute this part automaticly ? Because all code that I posted is in an action of a button and when I press button it execute all this code (code in answer). So is possible in I way `alertBody` to execute by itself ?

Comment: Yes. But I'm confused as how you invoke it is nothing to do with what you use as a seed to it. Is this therefor a new question now, or do you think there is some connection?

Comment: No there is connection.

Comment: You can make it execute itself just by putting it in a function and that function being called when the app launches, or when a view loads, or schedule it to run based on a timer. Lots of ways

Comment: @ThePumpingLama I'm trying to make it with timer.

Comment: Then time for a new question as its no longer anything to do with your origin al one

Comment: @Emi you will need to set up multiple notifications with a different sound assigned to each one.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is correct. Maybe you haven't tried your code enough and had a long string of extreme values.

[image]

Comment: Ya, I know and I tried many times, but I can't understand why it won't change. I think when notification execute it catch only one String from array, and it won't change. So maybe this works only on executing.